# Rake aborted! Invalid CSS after " filter: progid": expected ";", was ":DXImageTransfo..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

When I do `git push heroku master` I get......

```
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
(in /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x)
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/public/assets
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "  filter: progid": expected ";", was ":DXImageTransfo..."
(in /tmp/build_klvg6evbve3x/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
.............
Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> Rails plugin injection
Injecting rails_log_stdout
Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
Procfile declares types      -> web
Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, worker
-----> Compiled slug size is 39.4MB
-----> Launching...
!Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
!We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.
```

then to....

```
To git@heroku.com:testapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:testapp.git'
```

I Don't have anything in my application.css that is `":DXImageTransfo..."` so I'm not sure whats happening.

Now this is an issue because using Twitter Bootstrap and Simple_form, my forms are messed up and I think this is the reason why. Anyway to fix this? What's going on here?

Comment: If you do a find in all files you will find this text. application.css is a bit misleading since Rails will compile all styles into application.css

Comment: i was getting similar errors with the lines like `filter:;` and i deleted those to solve it :(!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with Microsoft Gradients. I kept getting errors based off only having Microsoft gradients in my css files. I fixed this by having them all deleted.

Answer (score 23):

Try to change following css code:

```
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

to

```
filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)");
```